# Vim - Increase number without changing column width

Tags: vim, vi

I'm dealing with a fixed-width file format and I need to increase all of the numbers in some columns. I have a simple macro that adds a value to a number, moves to the next line and repeats (like 2aj) However, these numbers start from 1 and usually end above 10000, so the column widths get messed up, e.g. (underscores as spaces, this example only covering the jump from 9 to 10)

```
FOO_7_BAR
FOO_8_BAR
FOO_9_BAR
```

becomes

```
FOO_9BAR
FOO_10_BAR
FOO_11_BAR
```

(note the new column of text that will break my program)

when I need

```
FOO_9_BAR
FOO10_BAR
FOO11_BAR
```

I have been manual going through and deleting a space from the first 9 columns, then 90, then 900, but I am looking for a more robust way to handle this without dealing with the first 10, 100, 1000, etc. with different macros or any manual input.

Thanks.

Comment: could this happen: you have 3 numbers in three lines, they are `7, 77 and 77777777`?  if it could happen, what would be the output?

Comment: Are these numbers the only thing on the line, or is there other text with them?

Comment: @Doorknob冰 There are many columns on either side with non-numerical characters

Comment: @Doorknob冰 but the program that will read this file only looks at a certain number of columns, like the three I tried to highlight in the example I made

Comment: Re: your edit, shouldn't the second code block have a space after `10` and `11`? If I'm understanding the question correctly, the lines are getting longer, which you don't want.

Comment: @Kent I'm sorry I don't understand your question

Comment: @Doorknob冰 That is correct, editing it in. You're understanding my issue

Comment: @MattThompson you said the number could be from 1 to 10000... please extend your `foo 8 bar` example, add a line how `1000` look like, `1000` has length 4, but 8 has only 1, I don't know what do you really want. or you need just a solution for your example?

Comment: Hmmm... so, ideally, you want all the lines to end up being the same length?

Comment: @Kent I chose 8 to 10 because 9 will go from taking up one column to two when it becomes to, kicking the BAR next to it over a column. The same happens when 99 becomes 100, 999 becomes 1000, so on

Comment: @Doorknob冰 yes. Imagine the part of the program that read BAR only looks for that data in columns #7 to #9. It used to read BAR but now it only read in BA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I come up with this way, I think the animation explains itself:

[image]

The final result is:

```
FOO 3 BAR
FOO 4 BAR
FOO 5 BAR
FOO 6 BAR
FOO 7 BAR
FOO 8 BAR
FOO 9 BAR
FOO10 BAR
FOO11 BAR
```

Comment: Oooh, neat trick. Didn't consider doing it in a new buffer. +1

Answer (score 2):

This requires a bit of manual hackery, but it's still better than manually deleting spaces.

You could also probably write a function that does this automagically, via Vimscript, though!

First, find the length of the shortest line. You can do this via ex. `:echo col("$")` on the shortest line.

Then, run the following command:

```
:g/.\{NUM\}/exec "norm! /[0-9]\<cr>X"
```

Replace NUM in the above command with the original number you got in the previous step.

Here's an explanation of how it works:

```
:g/.\{NUM\}/    Find lines that are too long
exec "norm!     A common idiom: build a string to execute in normal mode
/[0-9]<cr>      Find the first number on the line
X               Delete the space before it (equivalent to "hx")
```

Then simply repeatedly run the same command (you can do this by pressing <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>Up</kbd><kbd>Return</kbd>) until all the lines are the same length—it will result in an error once this is the case (since it won't find any matching lines).

Here's a short animation of the entire process:

[image: animation]

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with `:s` and a sub-replace expression.

```
:%s/\v([^0-9]*)(\d+)/\=strpart(submatch(1), 0, 5 - len(submatch(2))).submatch(2)
```

The idea is we capture the portion before the digits and the digits themselves. The replacement execute an vim expression via `\=` which put the two capture groups back together. However slice the first capture group via `strpart()` to a fixed width (5 in this example) minus the length of our second capture group, `len(submatch(2))`.

For more help see:

```
:h sub-replace-expression
:h strpart()
:h len()
```